# An error: configured the header search paths

Tags: objective-c

I wanted to use cocoapods in an old project, but it gave me an error: *library not found for -lPodsxxx*.

And the following tips:

*xxx target overrides the `HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.release.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation

```
- Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or

- Remove the build settings from the target.*
```

I configured it according to the prompt Build Settings -> Header Search Paths *$(inherited)*, and pod update success.

But I compile a new error: *'libxml/tree.h' file not found* 。

So I've been reconfigured Build Settings -> Header Search Paths
 *${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2* 。
But it also appeared in front of the problems.

I need help.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem.

Build Settings - > Header Search Paths

configure like this:

$(inherited)

${SDKROOT}/usr/include/libxml2